# Making Javascript resizable handlers on the borders of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Dear experts,
I am currently working on an code that allows users to drag & resize HTML elements across the pages. I could tackle the draggable no problem. But the problem comes from resizing. I don't know how attach Event Listeners to the "borders" of this elements to trigger the resize, specifically only the "right and bottom" borders.

I am aware of the similar approach on the Jquery UI, but I do not want to use the Jquery UI.

I would like to do it myself with vanilla Javascript and Jquery API.

I have spent the whole day searching on Google for a proper tutorial but failed. 
If you could point me to the right direction I would really appreciate.

Dennis

Comment: why dont u use the jquery resizable ?

Comment: because he writes he doesnt want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery ui appends 8 elements on top of your draggable element. south, southwest, west... and so on. Is it what you meant?

Comment: "appends 8 elements on top of your draggable element"thats exactly the inspiration i needed

Answer (score 0):

How do users resize them without dragging? if they just input a number have you tried the following

```
$(element).width(widthInput);
$(element).height(heightInput);
```